# Setting the background of a MasterDetailPage to be transparent

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.forms

When I try to set the background color of the Master (of the MasterDetailPage) to transparent, it stays white.

Basically what I would want to see, is that the color from the detail page is shown through the Master.

**FOR EXAMPLE** (If the above were true, then the background color of this MasterDetailPage would be red (Yes I know I can just set the background colour as red, but I want it to be **transparent**))

[image: Master should be red]

Comment: I notice that the effect from your screenshot is different from the official sample. If we run the official sample on iPad, the master page will overlap on the detail page. The effect(push and compress the detail page) is iPhone's. Could you please share some code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After seeing the TabletMasterDetailRenderer's [documentation](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/d3d59ee4f0b3098457e1debe8d7b03d0d0061a53/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS/Renderers/TabletMasterDetailRenderer.cs), we can find that the master or detail page which we create in PCL will be added on the `_masterController.View` and `_detailController.View`.

So when we set its `BackgroundColor` to `Transparent`, the page will still be white as what we look. We should also set the `_masterController.View`'s `BackgroundColor`.

We can find the `_masterController` in renderer and set it like:

```
public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews()
{
    base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews();

    var master = ViewControllers[0];
    master.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

    //This is Detail ViewController
    var detail = ViewController.ChildViewControllers[1];
}
```

Create a custom renderer for `MasterDetailPage` and put this code in it.

Comment: @Bracefor Glad it helps you.

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore. [MasterDetailRenderer.cs](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/master/Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android/Renderers/MasterDetailRenderer.cs) does not contain `ViewWillLayoutSubviews()`